# Limiting webpage content access by IP address

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to install a Symfony2 to my domain, but before the development I need to limit the access of the domain to only my IP address.

I tried this to the .htaccess located in the webroot:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 222.222.222.222
```

It does not work.

It just let no one see the website ... if i change deny from all to allow from all.. it's working, but i don't need this. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

this will block all traffic except traffic from 222.222.222.222

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 222.222.222.222
```

if you want to block just 1 ip, you need

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 222.222.222.222
Allow from all
```

Comment: Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 222.222.222.222

I copied exactly your code :(

Comment: thats strange as the exact code i use for my entire htaccess is Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 94.193.83.67
Allow from 94.170.219.166

Options +FollowSymLinks
ServerSignature Off
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType text/css .css

Comment: is that possible to there is some problem with the file itself?

Comment: must have something in the apache httpd.conf such as AllowOverride none set or something like that preventing you from doing this in htaccess. do you have root access to the server? also, with no htaccess at all, can you access the file correctly?

Comment: i dont have root access :s

now I created a new .htaccess and now there is no internal server error and Allow from all any Deny from all is working absolutely, BUT i cant add an exception as IP to limit or to not limit the access by..

Comment: i did it with this its working now

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx$
RewriteRule . - [F]

Comment: looks like AllowOverride none is set then if your able to do this via rewrite but now allow deny